# Should inclusive language linting be part of post submission?

Tags: discussion, inclusivity

I recently came across an answer to a question (deliberately not linking) that used the term `blacklist` in both description and code. It answered the question appropriately and well.

Although appropriate it could have been something else. At first I requested the answering user to modify the term to something more neutral but on second thoughts I didn’t like my tone and deleted the comment. I did consider editing the post but it didn’t feel right at that point.

This got me to wondering if an inclusive language bot could be an impersonal nudge to a writer to create better language? I’m aware that `blacklist` has an old etymology but that shouldn’t be a barrier to evolving the way we speak and write.

The feature request is a submit phase linter for problematic terms and an associated pop up thesaurus because naming is hard. Suggestions would be optional and user should only see once per post.

Suggested words to rewire could include blacklist, whitelist, master, slave to start with.

Comment: "Blacklist" isn't of Stack Overflow origin. Firstly, it is a term coined in the 1600s, and it means to put something in a pile where people know to ignore it. It doesn't have any other meaning than that. Dont' analyze it any further.

Comment: I also want to say that there really isn't a better term for certain electronic things than master and slave. For example, I2C communication. Until NXP changes the standard, master and slave are the correct terms.

Comment: Why no problem with the term 'whitelist'?  This question is clearly racist:)

Comment: @10Repsaysgetvaccinated 1639 is the first recorded use in a play script and was a list of people not to be trusted. I don’t need to overthink what it means in a comp sci context because I have that privilege. Put yourself in the shoes of a young programmer who has experienced systemic racism their entire life. Is the term so harmless then when other words are just as descriptive?

Comment: @WarrenBurton If I am a young black programmer for instance, and I get offended by the term "blacklist", then I am overthinking everything. Plus there is no better term, as "whitelist" is also racist (people will say it is white supremacy). I don't get what the proposal here is.

Comment: Just curious: are there any public survey results that show how black communities really feel about `black*` words that are commonly used? And what do they think of the [proposals](https://jmla.pitt.edu/ojs/jmla/article/view/490/744) in recent years to change those terms? _> Put yourself in the shoes of a young programmer..._  There is absolutely no doubt that they experience racism. I myself am only half-Asian but still experience racism and mockery (personally, I don't care much). But I do doubt that simply changing vocabularies actually helps them experiencing less racism.

Comment: Also worth reading https://mooseyanon.medium.com/github-f-ck-your-name-change-de599033bbbe which reflects my thoughts and shares the [same doubts mentioned in my previous comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/404562/should-inclusive-language-linting-be-part-of-post-submission#comment820125_404562). And the [discussion on Hacker News](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=26487854) shows that even black engineers aren't welcoming this kind of push to change the `*black*` / `master` words in the SW industry. It clearly shows that the black community wasn't even involved in this change

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This exact topic has been discussed previously on Uber Meta in the post '[What is Stack Exchange's official stance on words such as “black list”, “white list”, “master”, “slave”, and so on?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/350880)'. You should definitely take some time to read through the responses there, because there are some excellent takes and points made, on both sides of the coin.

[@curiousdannii](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/256282/curiousdannii) penned a [particularly excellent response](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/350884), which is especially worth a read. It was actually quoted in [the official SE response](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/352702), and I will include that quoted excerpt here, since it echoes the prime concern quite succinctly:

> …inasmuch as Stack Overflow and the other technology sites form a sort of documentation of technology, I don't think that there can be any blanket ban on such terminology. Many technology projects have used these terms and you cannot have useful or clear documentation or explanations of these projects if it is forbidden to use the terminology used by those projects.
>
> As projects change one-by-one to avoid these terms, especially if there is a general consensus to do so (which I think will probably happen for a term like 'slave' but I think it's likely will not happen for 'blacklist'), then there will be a reduction in how many posts use these terms here. But as questions can be asked about older technology it will remain a fact of life that these terms will continue to be used here.

Of course we want all users, from all backgrounds, to feel welcome here, full-stop. If certain terminology is offensive or hurtful to some, we should consider and discuss what can be done to mitigate that pain and take care of those members that feel hurt.

We also need to bear in mind the consequences of such changes to language as these, and reckon with whether they are actually a net *loss* if they lead to a decrease in clarity about present or past technologies. We should be careful not to lose sight of Stack Overflow's goal as a repository of useful knowledge while we pursue being a community inclusive to people of all backgrounds and kinds.

Comment: (Is *"both sides of the coin"* idiomatic (not a rhetorical question)? There is the [other side(s) of the coin](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/other_side_of_the_coin#Noun) and [two sides of the same coin](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/two_sides_of_the_same_coin).)

Comment: @Peter You've got me second guessing whether that's a real phrase now lol. I suppose it is idiomatic; I was using it to mean "2 sides of the same issue," that is, responses from both stances.

Comment: I agree with this answer.... it is treating the question more broadly, which I certainly like.

Comment: It's not especially common, @PeterMortensen, but it does exist as a idiom, has for many years, and should be well-understood by analogy to other similar idioms (if not just obvious from familiarity with real-world concepts).

Answer (score 12):

No, it shouldn't.

Those who consider these well-established terms 'problematic' avoid using them already. And those who don't (I, for instance) will find the proposed pop-up thesaurus annoying, and will of course ignore it, or seek ways to turn it off. So, at least for now, such a feature would be useless at best.

Answer (score 10):

The term "blacklisted" or "blacklist" isn't mostly used in a racist connotation, therefore it shouldn't be disallowed.

[According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blacklisting#Origins_of_the_term),

> The English dramatist Philip Massinger used the phrase "black list" in his 1639 tragedy The Unnatural Combat.

In that play, the term is used to describe a list of people who are untrustworthy and were murderers. Basically if they were blacklisted, then they shouldn't be trusted.

"Whitelisted" or "whitelist" is also racist (people will say it is white supremacy). In fact, people will take offense at almost anything these days.

> I’m aware that blacklist has an old etymology but that shouldn’t be a barrier to evolving the way we speak and write.

It depends on how the term is used. If the term is used in a racist way, then please flag it for moderator attention. But iff the term is used in a normal way, then it is the loss of the person getting offended by it.

It's like the COC used to say:

> Assume good faith.

Comment: What should those terms be renamed to anyways? In `tkinter` a child widget will always be referenced as a "slave widget" in code.